# PHPUnit: how to test that methods are called in incorrect order?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I want to use PHPUnit to test that methods are called in the right order.

My first attempt, using `->at()` on a mock object, did not work. For example, I expected the following to fail, but it does not:

```
  public function test_at_constraint()
  {
    $x = $this->getMock('FirstSecond', array('first', 'second'));
    $x->expects($this->at(0))->method('first');
    $x->expects($this->at(1))->method('second');

    $x->second();
    $x->first();
  }
```

The only way I could think of that forced a failure if things were called in the wrong order was something like this:

```
  public function test_at_constraint_with_exception()
  { 
    $x = $this->getMock('FirstSecond', array('first', 'second'));

    $x->expects($this->at(0))->method('first');
    $x->expects($this->at(1))->method('first')
      ->will($this->throwException(new Exception("called at wrong index")));

    $x->expects($this->at(1))->method('second');
    $x->expects($this->at(0))->method('second')
      ->will($this->throwException(new Exception("called at wrong index")));

    $x->second();
    $x->first();
  }
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Look at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21vendor%21phpunit%21phpunit-mock-objects%21PHPUnit%21Framework%21MockObject%21Matcher%21InvokedAtIndex.php/function/PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_InvokedAtIndex%3A%3Averify/8

Comment: I think that will help but I'm not sure.

Comment: That page seems to indicate that `->at()` will not cause a failure if its method is called at a different index, which my first test case already proves. Was there something else you had in mind from that page that would be useful?

Comment: I was thinking you could use a combination of `at` and `verify` somehow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need involve any `InvocationMocker` to make your expectations work. For example this should work:

```
public function test_at_constraint()
{
    $x = $this->getMock('FirstSecond', array('first', 'second'));
    $x->expects($this->at(0))->method('first')->with();
    $x->expects($this->at(1))->method('second')->with();

    $x->second();
    $x->first();
}
```

Comment: Other than the fact that it fails with "Mocked method does not exist" in my phpunit version, this works! AWESOME!

Comment: This works with PHPUnit 9.5.0 but raises a warning: The at() matcher has been deprecated. It will be removed in PHPUnit 10. Please refactor your test to not rely on the order in which methods are invoked.